# How are Cytotoxic T cells transfered?

Tags: immune-system, vaccination, mhc

We learned that Cytotoxic T cells are MHC dependent, and if CMH matchup doesn't occur between the T cell and the cancer cell for example, the former won't attack the latter.
If this is the case then how are T cells given through vaccines and transfers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T cells are not transferred. Vaccines induce the host to expand their own T cells that are responsive to the antigens that are given.

Comment: Adoptive cell transfer incl. TIL and CAR-T are forms of T cell transfers, though.

Comment: First, they're still almost invariably autologous, and second, given that the question seems to come from a fairly naive viewpoint it doesn't seem worth confusing the issue. If the OP would like expansion on these, they should clarify the question.

Comment: I thought the same thing, fair enough.